# Linear and affine transformations preserve convexity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose A is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and T is a linear function, $T: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$. Prove TA is convex and Aff(TA)=T(Aff(A)).

Ok the fist part is pretty staightforward, for the second part,

Let $x,y \in A, \lambda \in [0,1]\\Aff(\lambda T(y) +(1-\lambda)T(x))\\=\lambda T(y) +(1-\lambda)T(x)\\=T(Aff(\lambda (y) +(1-\lambda)(x))=T(\lambda (y) +(1-\lambda)(x))=\lambda T(y) +(1-\lambda)T(x)$

Since the constant term is $0$

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Aff here? Is it the spanned affine subspace? Note that the statement is also true for $T$ affine transformation (as the title suggests), i.e. $T(x)=L(x)+c$ for some linear $L\ $ and $\ c\in\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: @Berci Aff(x) = F(x)+C, where F is linear and C is a constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is convex and $T$ is linear, then if $x_1,x_2 \in TA$, there must exists $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $x_k =T a_k$. Let $ \lambda \in [0,1]$. Since $A$ is convex, $\lambda a_1+(1-\lambda) a_2 \in A$, hence $\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2 = T(\lambda a_1+(1-\lambda) a_2)\in TA$. Hence $TA$ is convex.

$\operatorname{aff} A = \{\lambda a_1 + (1-\lambda) a_2 | \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, a_1,a_2 \in A \}$.

$x \in \operatorname{aff} TA$ **iff** $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $x = \lambda T a_1 + (1-\lambda) Ta _2$ **iff** $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $x = T(\lambda a_1 + (1-\lambda) a _2)$ **iff** $x \in T(\operatorname{aff} A)$.